# Test exit! with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, exit

How can I test with RSpec some code with [`#exit!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exit-21)?

```
def method
  ...
rescue MyError => e
  logger.error "FATAL ERROR"
  exit! 1
end
```

I can test this code with `#exit` method because raise the `SystemExit` exception.

```
it "logs a fatal error" do
  lambda do
    object.method
    expect(logger).to have_received(:error).with("FATAL ERROR")
  end
end

it "exits" do
  expect { object.method }.to raise_error(SystemExit)
end
```

I'm not sure if I can achieve something similar. I'm thinking to reimplement the `exit!` method in `Kernel` module, just only for the specs. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just stub it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stub the `exit!` method for the object:

```
it "logs a fatal error" do
  lambda do
    allow(object).to receive(:exit!)
    object.method
    expect(logger).to have_received(:error).with("FATAL ERROR")
  end
end

it "exits" do
  expect(object).to receive(:exit!)

  object.method
end
```

Comment: The problem is that when RSpec read `exit!` stop to running the next tests.

Comment: I cannot create a double object of the class under test. Can you provide a more complete example, please?

Comment: sure you can - what I wrote simply replaces your `"exits"` test case

Comment: Added the first test case as well, where there is a stub for `exit!` as well.